# FMX: How to determine if drawing will be anti-aliased from TCanvasQuality?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I draw on a TCanvas and the result with be anti-aliased or not depending on the state of TCanvas.Quality (of type TCanvasQuality). It seems that I can always assume the following regardless of platform.

- TCanvasQuality.HighQuality results in anti-aliased drawing
- TCanvasQuality.HighPerformance results in non anti-aliased drawing

However, how can I determine what the result will be with TCanvasQuality.SystemDefault? It seems that Windows 10/11 will give anti-aliased and Android 8 will give non anti-aliased from my tests, but will that always be the case? Is there a way to tell for any platform / device?

Comment: Have a look inside `TCanvasGpu.CreateFromBitmap`. I suspect `SystemDefault` might be determined by TCanvas descendants. This might give you an idea how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks. That did help a bit but left me confused. TCanvasGpu.CreateFromBitmap implies that anti-aliasing (TMultisample.FourSamples) is only used for TCanvasQuality.HighQuality. That matches what I see on Android devices but not Windows, where SystemDefault is also anti-aliased. Perhaps SystemDefault is changed to one of the others somewhere else? I will continue looking.

Comment: I have never used FMX before but by looking at the code it seems that what you are seeing is another `TCanvas` descendant handling `SystemDefault` a bit differently. My observation might not help you answer your question but at least it might help explain whats happening in the background. Different `TCanvas` descendants for different platforms and probably also for different hardware acceleration modes, I suspect.